# iperf3 uses TCP even if UDP is specified

Tags: networking, network-traffic

I've encountered this issue with iperf3(version 3.1.3). iperf(2.0.5) works different. So, with iperf3 even if I specify that I want to use UDP, when I start a capture on the destination, first thing I see is TCP connection, then some UDP data and then the actual UDP datagrams for the test.

e.g. I sent 4 packets:

```
iperf3 -c 10.0.0.2 -u -p 1813 -V -k 4
```

Any ideas if this can be changed to send only the UDP packets or this is by design and cannot be changed? With iperf(2.0.5) now, I see only UDP traffic as I
would expect.

Comment: Do you capture on the `1813` port at the remote? If you use SSH to access the destination, SSH packets go over a TCP connection.

Comment: Nope. No SSH. I have 2 VMs and I access them directly. I start the capture on the destination. There is no difference on where I run the capture.